# jQuery Boostrap Carousel Show content according to current slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap jquery carousel to slide content. I also have some content below the carousel. This content should hide/show according to which slide is showing.

Since bootstrap uses active on the current slide I wrote the code below. 
Now this works when I use the arrows. But if I use keyboard arrows for next and previous, or when the slide is autoplay, the content does not show/hide accordingly.

jQuery:

```
    $('#success-stories .carousel-control.left, #success-stories .carousel-control.right').click(function() {
        if ( $('#success-stories .item1').hasClass("active") ) {
            $('.success1').removeClass("active"); 
            $('.success2').addClass("active"); 
        }
        if ( $('#success-stories .item2').hasClass("active") ) {
            $('.success2').removeClass("active"); 
            $('.success1').addClass("active"); 
        }

    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please my friend, the given events by bootstrap will help you... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: why don't you keep the content inside the `div` which is sliding??

Comment: I find an old exemple that can show you the way for using the event : http://jsfiddle.net/35DGj/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Text After Bootstrap Slide Action Using JQuery Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933255/show-text-after-bootstrap-slide-action-using-jquery-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of ways to implement this. Depending on what version of bootstrap you are running, you can use the `slid`, `slide` or `slide.bs.carousel`.

### Bootstrap Versions before 3

You can try this (depending on what version of bootstrap you are running), with the slid function, it detects when the slide event is completed:

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel()
 $("#myCarousel").bind("slid", function(){
    $currentActive = $("#myCarousel .active").attr('id');
       if($currentActive == "item1"){
           //then show something
       }else if(...){....}
  })
```

using the slide and the slid event you can find current slide and the next slide/target slide, this solution hasn't been tested yet but it should work fine.

```
$('.carousel').on('slide',function(e){
    var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
    var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    if(slideTo == 1){
       //do something for item one, realise here i am working with indexes
    }
});
```

### In bootstrap 3:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  //according to the documentation this event is fired when the slide method is invoked

    var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
    var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    if(slideTo == 1){
       //do something for item one, realise here i am working with indexes
    }
})
```

---

### Update

Why not give your success-content children div ids and instead of using the class to identify them, you use their individual ids. 
for example:

```
 <div id="success-content">
                <div class="success1 active" id="successOne">
                    <h4 class="rounded-heading">Eleanor's Story</h4>
                    <p>
                        <span class="quote-start"></span>
                             Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
                        <span class="quote-finish"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Isobel Leeds)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        All case studies are genuine photographs and un-retouched case studies of our own patients treated in our own clinics. (Reproduced with their consent)
                    </p>

                </div><!-- end success1 -->
                <div class="success2" id="successTwo">
                    <h4 class="rounded-heading">Melsor's Story</h4>
                    <p>
                        <span class="quote-start"></span>
                             Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
                        <span class="quote-finish"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Isobel Leeds)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        All case studies are genuine photographs and un-retouched case studies of our own patients treated in our own clinics. (Reproduced with their consent)
                    </p>
                </div>              
            </div><!-- end success-content -->

        </div><!-- end success-stories -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise explanation. You're the man!